# Dropdown click event in php and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i have the requirement when 1 option selected from dropdownlist then show associated data with that selected option.

here is code for dropdown list

```
<select class="op" name="emp" id ="tab4">
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
    <?php
     foreach ($empd as $row):
   echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "' >" . $row['employee_name'];
     ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
  </select>
```

so when option selected it should pass selected id to the controller and show associated data with that id using ajax
and this is script

```
<script>
        $('.op').click(function(){
            console.log("asdd")
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType:"json",
            url: "http://localhost/...",
            data: $('#tab4 :input')
            success:function(result){
            }
            });
            });
    </script>
```

ajax call is not working

Comment: This line - `data: $('#tab4 :input')` is incomplete/syntax error. Possibly `$('#tab4 :input').val()`, and missing ending comma -> `data: $('#tab4 :input').val() ,`

Comment: Also, have you tried `$('.op').change(` instead of `$('.op').click(`

Comment: Also, you are not closing your options `</option>` -> `echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "' >" . $row['employee_name'];` should be `echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "' >" . $row['employee_name']. "</option>";`

Comment: @Sean function mention in url is getting call but i m not getting id of selected value

Comment: That would have been helpful information to add in your question, instead of just `ajax call is not working`. Since you are already binding to the select, you could do `data: $(this).val(),` or using the id `$('#tab4').val(),` (the `:input` is not needed)

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="op" name="emp" id ="tab4">
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
    <?php
     foreach ($empd as $row):
   echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "' >" . $row['employee_name']."</option>";
     ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
  </select>
```

fire  event on change of dropdown

```
$('#tab4').on('change',function()
    {
            $.ajax({
                       type: "GET",
                       url: "http://localhost/...",
                       data: //data,
                       success: function(result){
                        // do something with result
                       }
                     });
    });
```

Comment: data to submit
$('#tab4').val()